# How to remotely control Trace32 via Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, embedded-linux, bamboo, trace32

I have an automated Linux agent (CentOS) with Bamboo to aid in building and deployment of new software onto a board. I want to be able to run .cmm files via Trace32 and a Lauterbach onto my locally located board using the remote Bamboo agent to trigger daily builds and deployment.

I am aware of the terminal command option: `./trace32 -s file.cmm` to avoid using the GUI.

Is there anyway I can use this kind of thing for remote deployment, perhaps utilising ssh?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Maybe even [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Some ideas concerning TRACE32: You can use the TRACE32 Remote API (search for api_remote.pdf in your installation) to control TRACE32 processes and some Lauterbach probes can also be controlled remotely (via ethernet).

Answer (score 2):

There is no SSH server in TRACE32. However you can control TRACE32 remotely via the TRACE32 remote API. See the document "api_remote.pdf" in the PDF folder of your TRACE32 installation.

To launch some scripts or execute some simple commands from a bash shell, you can use the command line tool **t32rem** from the <t32>/bin/linux folder.
This tool uses the TRACE32 remote API to send TRACE32 commands to open TRACE32 GUIs.

Do the following:

1. Enable the TRACE32 remote API to add the following two lines to your TRACE32 configuration file (usually "config.t32")

   ```
   RCL=NETASSIST
   PORT=20000
   ```

   You have to ensure that there is an empty line before and after these lines in your configuration file.
2. Launch TRACE32 and send a command to it with t32rem like that:

   ```
   t32rem localhost port=20000 <command>
   ```

   For *<command>* you can choose any TRACE32 command like `DO file.cmm` to execute your mentioned PRACTICE script.

For more complex remote control of TRACE32  (e.g. from a Python script) you should have a look at the previously mentioned "api_remote.pdf" and the examples at <t32>/demo/api.

Comment: In "t32rem localhost port=200000 <command>" you accidentally added an extra 0

Comment: You are right. Port numbers may of course not exceed 16 bit. I've fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

When you already have a command to run, how about using a [Script task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html) in your plan, so that you can execute the command you wanted?